# character counter and limiter is getting a Nan error

Tags: javascript, nan

```
var cat = prompt("What Do You Want To Tweet??!").length;

if (cat >= 140) {
    confirm("Sorry but your Tweet was over the 140 character limit by: " + cat - 140);
    confirm("You need to resubmit a Tweet that is not over the 140 Character limit");
} else {
    confirm("Success, Your Tweet has been posted!");
}
```

---

I have tried a bunch of different things, but this Nan error is always my final hurdle that I cant get by. I am pretty sure that the cat var isnt being seen as a number but I dont know how to make the computer see it as a number and I am pretty sure I only need to know the very basics to do this. I have also tried moving the .length around but to no avail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
confirm("Sorry but your Tweet was over the 140 character limit by: " + (cat - 140));
```

This is because `+` is left-associative. So it was first appending `cat` to the message, and then trying to subtract `140` from that. That tries to convert the message to a number, which doesn't work and returns `NaN`.

BTW, when you do `cat = prompt(...).length`, you get the length but you lose the tweet. You need to put the response in a variable and then get its length:

```
var tweet = prompt(...);
var cat = tweet.length;
```

Comment: Thanks for such a fast comment and I understand why I was wrong. If my assignment needs me to have the response in the confirm boxes I will keep what you said in mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with length, It has to do with order of operations

Your code is basically

```
("string" + cat) - 140
```

you need to add parenthesis around the calculation so it will do the calculation before the concatenation.

```
"string" +  (cat - 140)
```

Comment: PEMDAS!! I totally forgot about it..!! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to what @Barmar said, you can avoid repeating 140 if you substract it at the beginning:

```
var cat = prompt("What Do You Want To Tweet??!").length - 140;
if(cat < 0) {
    confirm("Success, Your Tweet has been posted!");
} else {
    confirm("Sorry but your Tweet was over the 140 character limit by: " + cat
      + "\n\n"
      + "You need to resubmit a Tweet that is not over the 140 Character limit");
}
```

However, consider allowing messages of 140 characters. IMO failing because being over 140 by 0 is weird.